# What are the differences between Desktop, Server, and Alternate Installs?

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to figure out what the exact difference is between the 3 different install Disks.

Like what packages are different and such.

For Example:
- The server disk doesn't install gnome by default and has the non-pretty install wizard.
- The Alternate Install gives options for encryption.

Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(just for the sake of doing it I have also included Ubuntu Netbook Edition here)

### Similarities between all versions

- All versions support encryption of the home folder.
- All versions use the same application repositories, so that you can for instance install web and mail servers on Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Desktop on a Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Netbook system (by installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package), and any other combination.

### [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)

- The installer is called [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity), which is written specifically to be a GUI installer for the Desktop/Live CD.
- Includes the [Wubi installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer) for installation for Windows systems
- Installs the basic Ubuntu system, in addition to the `ubuntu-desktop` package and all its dependencies, including GNOME and various applications, such as Firefox and Empathy.
- You can try the system directly from the CD, and it has a graphical installation.

### [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/server)

- The installer is [debian-installer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer), which is text based and is shared with Debian.
- It basically is just the base Ubuntu system, but during the installation you can optionally install services such as a web or mail server by using tasksel.
- Ubuntu Server does not include a graphical user interface so it does **not** install the applications included in the `ubuntu-desktop` package, such as GNOME.

### [Ubuntu Netbook](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook)

- Installs the basic Ubuntu system, in addition to the `ubuntu-netbook` package and all its dependencies. It also uses the Unity interface instead of the default GNOME interface.
- The installation method is very similar to Ubuntu Desktop

### [Ubuntu alternate installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

- The installer is [debian-installer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer), which is text based and is shared with Debian.
- The alternate installer installs the `ubuntu-desktop` package, just as Ubuntu Desktop does.
- It is mostly intended for installing or upgrading Ubuntu on machines where this cannot be done in other ways. For instance, I had to use this CD when installing Ubuntu on my machine, because none of the LiveCDs would work.
- Allows setup of LVM and LUKS encrypted file systems
- Has an option for an "OEM Install", which allows you to install the OS but leave the personalization like username and password as part of the first boot.
- Option to install an [LTSP Server](http://www.ltsp.org/).

Comment: Does this still hold true for 14.04? For once, there's no  alternate installer anymore :(

Also, does Ubuntu Server not allow setting up LVM and LUKS encrypted file systems at install time?