# what is the difference between amd64 and x64; what is 'alternate' version in ubuntu download page

Tags: downloads

What's the difference between amd64 and x64?

---

Why is there no version listed as x86 on the Ubuntu download page?

And what do the sub-categories mean?

1. alternate
2. desktop
3. server

What's this 'alternate" version all about?

Comment: Are you trying to understand which image you need? If you want to know the differences between the amd64 and x86 or if you want to know what the alternate version is, the question was already asked before as you can see in my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

x86, i386, i686 are architectures which refer to 32-bit machines. x64, ia64 and amd64 refer to 64-bit machines. See. also [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3378/6969)

For the difference between the alternate, desktop and server versions, see [What are the differences between Desktop, Server, and Alternate Installs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17952/6969)

Comment: My desktop is using the x86_64 architecture. Unless I'm mistaken, the ia64 is not part of the Intel Pentium marketplace or history whatsover, but is rather the Intel Itanium such as used in HP-9000s of recent vintage.

Answer (score 3):

One question at a time. Is that not the rule? Here is the answer to the first question in your title. A simple search found this link:

[Explanation of how the label AMD64 originated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Notice these quotes:

> The original specification was created by AMD
>
> After launching the architecture under the "x86-64" name, AMD renamed it AMD64 in 2003

So, the answer is:"Not much difference."

As for part of of your second question, see this link

[Ubuntu explanation of why there is an alterative CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download)

Note the heading Alternative Installer Details.

As for the difference between a desktop computer and a computer that is doing work as a server, I suggest that you ask that as a separate question. Different Ubuntu editions for different computer use.

Comment: I guess that the OP is confused by the available images, so although the actual answer is different for both, the original question did not expect that.