# "Try Ubuntu" on Grub menu is not displayed

Tags: 11.10, usb, grub2

I've downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 ISO image.
Following the steps described on Unbutu.com site I've created a USB stick with the above image (using Startup Disk Creator from a Ubuntu 11.04 PC)
Rebooting the system I can see just "INSTALL Ubuntu" as first item in the menu.
I cannot see "Try Ubuntu" option.

PS: I've also tried to follow "Install Ubuntu" but in the end the wizard for disk partition is displayed and it suggests to erase my "master" HD.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

An option for a live CD (*"Try out Ubuntu"*) is only provided from the [Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17952/what-are-the-differences-between-desktop-server-and-alternate-installs/17955#17955) installation CD but not from the Alternate CD.

You may want to download the image for the [Desktop CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download) to be able to try out Ubuntu without installation.