# Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS installation mode "Install a command-line system" missing?

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, mode

I just wanted to install a command-line system from my Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS ISO and the option for that is missing. Am I missing something in the process or what could be the fault?  Trying to use it within a VirtualBox VM.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install Ubuntu Server instead of Ubuntu desktop.

Ubuntu server comes without the GUI part of Ubuntu (which means it doesn't have the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package installed). So it only has a command line.

During installation of Ubuntu Server, it asks you what packages/servers you want to install (apache, mysql, etc.). Of course you will be able install them later, even if you didn't choose the packages during installation.

Comment: But what does this screenshot show then: [screenshot](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lk965-DczhE/UgYYw1MGIZI/AAAAAAAAAvk/2e7nLnzaNKY/s1600/Ubuntu+%5BRunning%5D+-+Oracle+VM+VirtualBox_003.png) In my understanding this is not a server installation ISO. The server ISO has the option "install minimal system".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that's the [alternate install CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso). Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/17955/8698) to find out the difference between each.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was searching for. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in the standard installation medium.
You could alternatively install [Ubuntu Server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso) or use the [minimal installation medium](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).