# Confusion about command-line system install

Tags: command-line, server, system-installation

I'd like to install a command-line only version of Ubuntu 12.04, but I do not have clear which installation media I should use: I understood that the classical "Ubuntu Desktop" does not contain the CL option, but then I found different answers:

1) I should use the Ubuntu Server version ([Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS installation mode "Install a command-line system" missing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409090/ubuntu-12-04-3-lts-installation-mode-install-a-command-line-system-missing))

2) No wait, the

> Server Install CD provides a simple command line system, but it is not the same as "install a command-line system"

and therefore I should use the "Alternate CD" version (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)

3) No, no, wait, the Ubuntu alternate installer still installs the `ubuntu-desktop` package ([What are the differences between Desktop, Server, and Alternate Installs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17952/what-are-the-differences-between-desktop-server-and-alternate-installs/17955#17955))

So which version do I need for a command-line system? Server or Alternate?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install server version, it comes with command line apps.AFAIK it does not come with `ubuntu-desktop`.

`Alternate version` is for computers with very low memory which can not load GUi based installer, it does not neccesarily mean that it does not contain any GUI, **it just has a text based installer instead of GUi based installer**.

So you should use Server edition.